# How to debug web API push notifications effectively?

Tags: android, debugging, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a Progressive Web App (**PWA**) for **Android**. Currently my **on device** web API push notifications debug workflow - after I installed the PWA through the **add to home screen** promot - looks like this:

1. Changed some code in the service-worker.js (Atom IDE)
2. Upload service-worker.js to server
3. Clean caches to remove the old service-worker
4. Generate and add the new Auth-Key for the push notifications receiver device (*to:*)
5. Send new push notification from the Terminal (latest Ubuntu)
6. Repeat until it works...

This is very time consuming. Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit: I'm still very interested in time saving solutions for this, thank you.**

Comment: you can automate push notifications using Appium. plus other services... but i use appium for android apps (not PWA)

Comment: Try checking this documentation about ["Debugging Service Workers" on the Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/) that talks about debugging your PWA service workers (including push notification). You can also check out their [own sample](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/tree/gh-pages/push-messaging-and-notifications). Also available are Peter Beverloo's [Notification Generator](https://tests.peter.sh/notification-generator/) and [Mozilla's Push Payload Demo](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_demo.html). Hope this helps.